# bash iterate over a directory sorted by file size

Tags: bash

As a webmaster, I generate a lot of junk files of code. Periodically I have to purge the unneeded files filtered by extention. Example: "cleaner txt" Easy enough. But I want to  sort the files by size and process them for the "for" loop. How can I do that?

**cleaner**:

```
#/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
echo "Please supply the filename suffixes to delete.";
exit;
fi;

filter=$1;

for FILE in *.$filter; do clear; 

cat $FILE; printf '\n\n'; rm -i $FILE; done
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ/003 (How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mix of `find` (to print file sizes and names), `sort` (to sort the output of `find`) and `cut` (to remove the sizes). In case you have very unusual file names containing any possible character including newlines, it is safer to separate the files by a character that cannot be part of a name: `NUL`.

```bash
#/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
echo "Please supply the filename suffixes to delete.";
exit;
fi;

filter=$1;

while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 3 FILE; do
  clear
  cat "$FILE"
  printf '\n\n'
  rm -i "$FILE"
done 3< <(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.$filter" \
  -printf '%s\t%p\0' | sort -zn | cut -zf 2-)
```

Note that we must use a different file descriptor than `stdin` (`3` in this example) to pass the file names to the loop. Else, if we use `stdin`, it will also be used to provide the answers to `rm -i`.

Comment: I don't understand much of this bash script as I am 74 and untrained in IT as well as CS. I have always been dependent on the kindness of strangers as well as the forbearance of reptiles. Your solution marks you as a computer professional and I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430385/222549), you could use the find command as follows:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.yaml" -printf "%s %p\n" | sort -n
```

`find` command prints the the size of the files and the path so that the sort command prints the results from the smaller one to the larger.

In case you want to iterate through (let's say) the 5 bigger files you can do something like this using the `tail` command like this:

```
for f in $(find ./ -type f -name "*.yaml" -printf "%s %p\n" |
           sort -n | 
           cut -d ' ' -f 2)
do 
    echo "### $f"
done
```

Comment: This will not work if file names contain spaces, newlines...

Answer (score 0):

If the file names don't contain newlines and spaces

```
while read filesize filename; do 
  printf "%-25s has size  %10d\n" "$filename" "$filesize"
done < <(du -bs *."$filter"|sort -n)

while read filename; do
  echo "$filename"
done < <(du -bs *."$filter"|sort -n|awk '{$0=$2}1')
```